# On which TextBox event should I call ICompletionNotify.SetComplete?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, extensions

I have a IToolControl derived control which contains a c# TextBox.
In the IToolControl::OnSetFocus function documentation, it states that you need to call ICompletionNotify::SetComplete() when it's finished to let the application know that the control should lose focus.

On another IToolControl ComboBox control, I called the SetComplete() function on the DropDownClosed event.

On which TextBox event should I call ICompletionNotify.SetComplete()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess an appropriate moment to call ICompletionNotify.SetComplete for a TextBox would be upon the user hitting the `Enter` key. That could be handled by subscribing to the [KeyDown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) event and checking whether the [KeyCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.keycode.aspx) in event arguments equals to [Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx)`.Enter`.